# How to change sorting order in "Currently Open Document" of TextWrangler?

Tags: macos, textwrangler

In 4.x, "Currently Open Document" of TextWrangler is sorted alphabetical order. In 5.5, it is sorted by modified datetime.

How can I change the sorting order to alphabetical again?

Comment: That's strange. Using 5.5.1 and everything sorts alphabetically. Can't even see any options in the software to change that... You try updating to latest patch or reinstalling?

Comment: @dr.nixon it's a one-time outcome after version upgrade (details in answer)

Answer (score 1):

Reply from TextWrangler support:

> Though TextWrangler 5 (like previous versions) does list open
>   documents in alphabetical order by default, the order of reopened
>   files right after a version upgrade may be arbitrary as a one-time
>   outcome.
>
> You can however correct this situation as follows:
>
> Create a new editing window (File -> New -> Text Window)    and
>   then drag all open documents into that window's file list,    where
>   TextWrangler should sort them in alpha order (as usual).